# bash sort is not sorting numerically on field as desired

Tags: bash, sorting

I've been trying to do a numeric sort on a list of file names.

They're all named as

> something.txt~NUM~

I've tried sorting them by

> sort -t "~" -k1 -k2n

But the sort comes out wrong.  If I do

> sort -n

Then they're numerically sorted as desired but the file handles aren't sorted.

Here's a test file

```
explanation.txt.~1~
explanation.txt.~2~
explanation.txt.~3~
explanation.txt.~4~
explanation.txt.~5~
explanation.txt.~6~
explanation.txt.~7~
explanation.txt.~8~
explanation.txt.~9~
explanation.txt.~11~
explanation.txt.~12~
explanation.txt.~13~
explanation.txt.~14~
explanation.txt.~15~
explanation.txt.~16~
explanation.txt.~17~
explanation.txt.~18~
explanation.txt.~19~
explanation.txt.~20~
presentation.txt.~10~
presentation.txt.~11~
presentation.txt.~12~
presentation.txt.~13~
presentation.txt.~14~
presentation.txt.~15~
presentation.txt.~16~
presentation.txt.~17~
presentation.txt.~18~
presentation.txt.~19~
presentation.txt.~1~
presentation.txt.~20~
presentation.txt.~21~
presentation.txt.~22~
presentation.txt.~2~
presentation.txt.~3~
presentation.txt.~4~
presentation.txt.~5~
presentation.txt.~6~
presentation.txt.~7~
presentation.txt.~8~
presentation.txt.~9~
```

which gets sorted as

```
explanation.txt.~11~
explanation.txt.~12~
explanation.txt.~13~
explanation.txt.~14~
explanation.txt.~15~
explanation.txt.~16~
explanation.txt.~17~
explanation.txt.~18~
explanation.txt.~19~
explanation.txt.~1~
explanation.txt.~20~
explanation.txt.~2~
explanation.txt.~3~
explanation.txt.~4~
explanation.txt.~5~
explanation.txt.~6~
explanation.txt.~7~
explanation.txt.~8~
explanation.txt.~9~
presentation.txt.~10~
presentation.txt.~11~
presentation.txt.~12~
presentation.txt.~13~
presentation.txt.~14~
presentation.txt.~15~
presentation.txt.~16~
presentation.txt.~17~
presentation.txt.~18~
presentation.txt.~19~
presentation.txt.~1~
presentation.txt.~20~
presentation.txt.~21~
presentation.txt.~22~
presentation.txt.~2~
presentation.txt.~3~
presentation.txt.~4~
presentation.txt.~5~
presentation.txt.~6~
presentation.txt.~7~
presentation.txt.~8~
presentation.txt.~9~
```

I'm running Sierra OSX.  So, in particular, `sort -V` is not available to me.  I also know how to get the desired result using a perl script.  So, it's not a matter of how to get the desired result, but how to do this using 'sort'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first want to sort *only* by field 1, and then in case of ties look at field 2:

```
sort -t'~' -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

When you use `-k1`, you are sorting by field 1 **up to** the end of line. When you do that, there are no ties, so the sorting by field 2 never kicks in.